# Which database design approach is correct for multiple client of single application.

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am working on project management application which have different client (Customer's). But UI for all client is same. Also i observed two type of approaches per db per client(multi-tenant) and single db for all client. But lack of my experience did not found which is better for me. I want to fully segregation of all client's. I have writing web services for accessing data from MySQL db to my application.please help how would be the table structure if multi-tenant or single db approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question and difficult to give specific advice without knowing specifics of your overall design, but in general I would say you should probably create one database for your application and enforce customer separation on the application level. To keep the client applications fully segregated from one another you simply implement different application-level authentication. Certainly there are advantages to each solution, but in my opinion that's probably the best way to handle it.